# converting IntPtr as c# struct pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, intptr

I have an unmanaged C++ function that reads like :`int myfunction(LPVOID p1, LPVOID p2)`

My wrapper in C# takes  `extern static int mywrapperFunction(IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2)`

Within my wrapper function definition, i want to deference IntPtr to a structure.

In C++:

```
int myfunction(LPVOID p1, LPVOID p2)
{
    (MYFIRSTSTRUCTURE *)abc = (MYFIRSTSTRUCTURE *)p1;
    (MYSECONDSTRUCTURE *)efg = (MYSECONDSTRUCTURE *)p1;
    //rest of the operation involves this abc and efg
}
```

I need to do similar thing in C#:

```
int mywrapperFunction(IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2)
{
   //how to consume IntPtr p1 and IntPtr p2 for C# structure similar to MYFIRSTSTRUCTURE and //MYSECONDSTRUCTURE
}
```

Comment: There was no good reason in the C++ code to declare these arguments void*, they should have been typed arguments.  There's even less of a good reason to do the same in C#.  Declare it the way it should be, it is int mywrapper(ref MyFirstStructure p1, ref MySecondStructore p2)

Comment: This is part of a big code which I didn't write and at this point I can't change it, I am just doing the wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to handle this is via [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.100).aspx).